# What were the main uses of the large CRT and light pen on early PDP computers?

Tags: input-devices

My first earliest experiences with "large" computers were an HP-2100 and a sigma-7, using a teletype and punch cards/line printer respectively.

I've stumbled upon an old image of a PDP-6 and PDP-6 [here](https://emptysqua.re/blog/grok-the-gil-fast-thread-safe-python/) which had a large (16 inch) circular CRT monitor (and it seems a light pen as well).

Where these experimental devices or special graphics applications, or were these used to program and/or operate the computers routinely? If so, how?

---

**below:** from ultimate.com [PDP-6 serials](http://www.ultimate.com/phil/pdp10/pdp6-serials.html)

[image]

---

**below x3:** from [PDP-1](http://www.computer-history.info/Page4.dir/pages/PDP.1.dir/)

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

**below x2:** from archive.computerhistory.org [PDP-1_Online](http://archive.computerhistory.org/resources/still-image/DEC/PDP-1_Online/)

[image]

[image]

Comment: two "contemporaries"of the PDP's, also with round displays:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZLD4.jpg and https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmdCv.jpg

Comment: [Spacewar!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacewar!), of course. :-)

Comment: @dirkt This is clearly the correct answer!

Comment: The equipment likely derives from radar installations (like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-Automatic_Ground_Environment), where having operator input on a radar display would be helpful. Since the Air Force bought a bunch they could easily be repurposed for other input tasks in the civilian world. (Recall in the 50's and 60's, the armed forces were a major driver for computer technology).

Comment: Could it have been flight smulators?

Comment: A routine use of a light pen I've observed not on a PDP, though, but on a [MIR-2 computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIR_%28computer%29). For text editing with a CRT display and an electric typewriter, the light pen was used pretty much the same way the mouse is used today to indicate the text insertion point, or to copy-paste.

Comment: By "main uses", are you asking for a list?  There's Spacewar, already commented.  There's project PEPR  (Precision Encoding and Pattern Recognition), There's SHRDLU for the PDP-6.  There are dozens of others.  My effort, which I included as an answer is dwarfed by any of the above.

Comment: @WalterMitty I think your answer is particularly interesting; (solving for, and then) envisioning molecular structure really leveraged every bit of technology available as it evolved, that must have been quite a lot of fun! So do you think it's safe to say that this is a specialized I/O device available to developers for a variety of applications, but for many uses or basic programming it was not required? Or was the CRT an essential part of computer operation? These are plenty of examples for me (others may enjoy seeing more) but it's the overall role I'm interested in. Thanks!

Comment: Jon Custer is correct with his comment on radar installations.  The Type 30 and 340 CRT was intended for radar.  It's coated with two phosphors: one with short persistance and one with long persistance.

Comment: Walter Mittys comment about flight simulator is interesting.  An early demonstration of ARPANET was running a flight simulator on the Harvard PDP-10, send the data to MIT for processing, and send it back to Harvard for viewing on a PDP-1.  Or something like that...

Comment: @LarsBrinkhoff if you don't use `@`replies correctly, those users will not receive a notification. See [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/303080)

Comment: HI @Chenmunka can you tell how my question managed to become untagged? I had a similar thing happen elsewhere and so far I didn't receive a clear answer there either. Thanks! ([How did my question become untagged?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1089/12102))

Answer (score 13):

I got a job in the summer of 1965, programming a PDP-6 to put a model of a protein molecule on the display, as a stick figure.  The molecule was 3D and the display was of course 2D, so I had to simulate depth.  I used perspective, shading, and motion.

The idea of the display was to allow a human crystallographer to evaluate the actions of another computer program, to see if they seemed real.  The other program, running on an IBM 7094, was bending and twisting the molecule so as to optimize something like bonding energy.

This was hard,  and I only had a couple of computer courses and a little random hacking under my belt at the time.  The hardest part was programming the modem that was networked to the IBM 7094.  It took me all summer just to get something going.

**Edit:** There are a number of applications that used the CRT on either the PDP-1 or the PDP-6.  These were all much more impressive than my efforts.  A partial list follows:

SHRDLU.  This is a program that could manipulate a virtual set of blocks using a virtual robotic arm.  It acted on the blocks, based on natural language input from the user.  The CRT was just to let the user see what SHRDLU was doing with the blocks.  The main focus of SHRDLU wasn't the display.  It was early exploration of natural language recognition.

Expensive Desk Calculator.  This was a predecessor of VisiCalc, Lotus 1-2-3, Excel, or any of the electronic spreadsheets.

Expensive Typewriter.  This was a predecessor of Word*Star, Word Perfect, Word, or any of the word processors.

Spacewar.  My favorite, and already mentioned in another answer.  Often used as a demo of the capabilities of the CRT. Predecessor of Space Invaders, Asteroids, or any of the video games.

Project PEPR.  (Precision Encoding and Pattern Recognition)  This was about automating the scanning and evaluation of millions of bubble chamber photographs.  The CRT was used for, among other things, showing the user an image of the current photograph.

I don't know whether the Harmony Compiler belongs in this list or not.  I'm not sure it used the CRT.  But it sure used the speakers!  This was a predecessor to the audio CD, MP3, and all that.

Comment: Were the display and light pen used by the OS at all, or only by applications?

Comment: At the time, there wasn't really an OS for the 6.  I was running on the raw iron.  Some other people may have had an OS available to them, but I didn't know about it.  The OS, if any,  would have been an early version of ITS.

Comment: Come to think of it,  DEC must have had an early version of the Monitor out by 1965, but I never saw it that summer.

Comment: If you want a really good application that used the CRT, look up SHRDLU.  SHRDLU's main focus was artificial intelligence, specifically natural language competence, but it used the CRT to show the user what its world looked like.

Comment: I'd consider adding the other applications you mentioned directly into your answer, comments are not considered permanent and can't be relied upon to remain.

Comment: What controlled the display timing?  Could one generate a bunch of coordinates, send them to the display as a group, and then have the hardware visit each in sequence while code worked on the next batch, or did one have to send each coordinate to the display individually?  If the latter, were there any timer-tick interrupts or other timer hardware resources to help the programmer output points at a uniform rate?

Comment: I've forgotten the details of how the CRT controller worked.  Hey, it's been over fifty years.  I think it had vectors, and I think I programmed it in the simplest possible way. I was just a college kid at the time, and not one of the grand wizards.

Comment: @supercat, the PDP-6 display is called the "Type 340" and documentation is available from Bitsavers.  There are several emulators.  In essence, yes, there were "groups".  The display hardware retrieves commands from the host computer by means of DMA or interrupts.  A sequence of such commands is called a display list.  The display executes the list autonomously until an END command at which point the host computer is interrupted.

Comment: @WalterMitty, if you want to expand your list, here are some more programs for the AI Lab PDP-6/10 and its Type 340 display: DDT, TECO, MacHack VI, munching squares, Life, a Datapoint terminal emulator, David Siver's flight simulator, Lisp, Logo, Dazzle Dart (ported from the Logo PDP-11), SUDS (ported from SAIL), Beeler's heart cell simulation, Speciner's gas simulation.

Comment: Also game of life and some graphics from Gosper.  It"s a long list.

Answer (score 5):

On the PDP1 at least they were used to play video games! Specifically SpaceWar, a predecessor to Asteroids (and every other top down game, really)

https://www.masswerk.at/spacewar/

Answer (score 4):

There was a system named Automatic Fingerprint Identification System that used PDP6, PDP8 and PDP11

Comment: Welcome to *Retrocomputing!*  This answer is too short.  Can you improve it by adding more detail about what this system was, and how it used the CRT and light pen?  Links to or quotations from other sources would also help.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer:

> Where these experimental devices

No. They could be ordered as standard options.

> or special graphics applications,

That was the intention. They where more like plotters or printers.

In fact, DEC made good sales of them as 'graphics terminals' on mainframes. The mainframe did whatever calculations and the results were either transmitted as a set of coordinates toward the PDP to display them directly (playing dumb terminal), or more often, the 'standard' (read: paper) output of the mainframe was redirected to the PDP, interpreted there by a special-to-type program to display a related graph. The latter was quite handy, as it required only small modifications to the mainframe applications and left all graphic interpretation (programming) to the 'intelligent' terminal.

> or were these used to program and/or operate the computers routinely?

There have been applications to use them that way, but otherwise not. Programming was still a job for punch tape and TTYs.

Answer (score 4):

### PDP-5's as wells

[image]

I just ran across the YouTube video [The Incredible Machine (1968)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwVu2BWLZqA) that shows the screen and light pen being used to do interactive circuit design and simulation.

GIF was made at about `02:44` in the video.

Once again, this is an example of a specific interface application, rather than to "program and/or operate the computers routinely."

From the video's caption:

> The Bell Labs 'Graphic 1' computer system consisted of a Digital Equipment Corporation '**PDP-5**' computer coupled with input devices such as the '**Type 370' light pen** and Teletype Corporation 'Teletype Model 33' keyboard, married to a Digital Equipment Corporation '**Type 340' precision incremental display** backed by 36-bit **Ampex 'RVQ' buffer memory** capable of storing 4096 'words'. The resolution on the monitor was 1024×1024.
>
> This system was designed to transform the graphics-based input into output to be fed into a IBM '7094' (200 Kflop/s). The entire thing was attached to a microfilm-based recorder - the Stromberg Carlson 'SC 4020', which took hours to read and record the data.

Answer (score 3):

You asked "Where these experimental devices or special graphics applications, or were these used to program and/or operate the computers routinely?"  I'm not sure this was answered directly?

The PDP-6 display is a Type 340, and the PDP-1 display is the similar Type 30.  The latter is "point plotting", i.e. there is a PDP-1 instruction to send the X, Y coordinates to draw a point.  Whereas with the Type 340, the PDP-6 will make a display list in mememory, from which the display will fetch instructions to draw points, lines, and characters by itself.

The Type 30 and Type 340 were not experimental.  They were in the stock DEC product list.  However the primary device used to operate the machines were teletypes, not CRT displays.  In that sense, the graphics applications were a bit special and not part of routine operation.

Answer (score 3):

I used to work for DEC. One of my customers had a GT40 that in conjunction with an 11/70 to make plots for radiation treatments.

Comment: Welcome to Retrocomputing Stack Exchange. Please read the [tour]. It'd be good if you could elaborate on this answer; how did it use the light pen, and how did it use the CRT?

Comment: I never saw it in action.  The main reason is that when I was there, there system would be down for maintenance. I did play lunar lander on it a few times, though.